# UITableView won't scroll behind blur views, tab bar, or navigation bar

Tags: swift, uitableview, interface-builder, uivisualeffectview

I'm making a simple app and I love using blue effects throughout the UI. Normally if I use a tableView I pin the 4 edges all the way out to the edge of the viewController, and everything scrolls correctly "behind" the blurred navigation bar and tab bar.

However, for one scene I want one view "Original Post VisualFX View" to be "pinned" at the top while the answer fields scroll behind that view and the nav/bottom bars.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the view hierarchy:

[image]

Even after I turned off "clip to bounds" on the tableview as well as every view in the hierarchy above it, I can only get the tableView to scroll a BIT behind the Original Post VisualFX View and the bottom tab bar before they disappear. I assume it's because tableViews don't draw things that aren't visible at all within its bounds.

I'm trying to do everything in the Storyboard in IB with as little code as possible. I feel like this shouldn't be that hard, right?

Comment: Change the order of the views so the table view comes before the visual FX view. If that doesn’t work, change their Z indexes via code making the FX view bigger than that of the table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after tinkering for a while, I found a workaround: use a TableViewController for the whole scene, and just use a custom TableViewCell as the header, which pins it at the top when you scroll. By using ClearColor for the background and putting a UIVisualEffectView with blur in the background, I'm able to get everything to work beautifully.